# Not showing a specific node while pushing the code in github

Tags: git, github

I have the following thing coming up when I am doing `git status`

```
$ git status
On branch POS-230252
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        node_modules/
```

I want it to be not shown while I try to push my changes, however I need the file to exist in my project.

Can anyone please give me an idea about how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those are *untracked* files.... so they won't be included when you push (unless they had been tracked before and then deleted/untracked, of course). So, the trick is to understand that git does *not* work on whatever you have on your working tree but on whatever is on the *revisions* that you are pushing.

If what you want is not to see that shown, you might choose to ignore it by putting it in `.gitignore` so that it's part of the project and everybody shares the setting when they checkout. Put this in `.gitignore`:

```
node_modules
```

At this point git should not care about that directory anymore. Then add .gitignore to the project, commit it, push and then everybody will have the same setting to ignore it.

Comment: Is there a way to put it in the gitignore?